# Can ColdFusion ORM handle Unicode string?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

How can I make CF9's ORM (aka Hibernate) save strings as unicode string?

I.e. use prefix `N'string'` in SQL Server

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<cfproperty name="showName" type="string" sqltype="nvarchar(50)" />
```

Comment: but the generated SQL statement still does Not have the N prefix though.  Are you saying as long as the sqltype is nVarChar, I don't need the N prefix?

Comment: Right, and also read this old blog post: http://www.sustainablegis.com/blog/cfg11n/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=F9553D86-20ED-7DEE-2A913AFD8651643F

Comment: And a more recent Google Groups discussion (you should subscribe to this group if you're going to do a lot more work with CF ORM) http://groups.google.com/group/cf-orm-dev/browse_thread/thread/5b72f738be1dfd57